# Serial driver HW FIFO over flow issue

Tags: serial-port, driver

We are using the following architecture. 
root@ti-omap3-am3517-evm:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 7 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 597.64
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x1
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : OMAP3517/AM3517 EVM
Revision        : 0020
Serial          : 0000000000000000

We are using Linux kernel version 2.6.32 
root@ti-omap3-am3517-evm:~# uname -a
Linux ti-omap3-am3517-evm 2.6.32.8 #71 PREEMPT Mon Nov 5 15:37:19 EST 2012 armv7l unknown

The issue (HW FIFO over flow) we are facing is with serial driver (driver/serial/8250.c) uart_rx_char(). The serial port has 64 bytes FIFO and it is configured to generate interrupt upon receiving 32 bytes.

We are reading/writing data from/to serial port at 460800 baud rate. The regression test runs over the period of 7-8 hours in which we send and receive data to/from the serial port. After a couple of hours what we see is that HWFIFO over flow happens and we have no clue why it is happening. 
We are assuming that either one of the following two things are happening.

1) The serial interrupt is skipped because other interrupts (Ethernet/ i2c and MMC (out of which we don't use MMC and i2c during the regression test ) in the systems takes too long that serial interrupts are skipped and by the time the serial ISR gets a chance to run the HW FIFO is already full.

2) The other assumption is that we must process the ISR in less than 1msec (one milisecond) as such 460800 bits per second => 460800/1000 ms ~= 460 bits/ms ~= 52bytes/ms and since we have configured serial port to generate interrupt at every 32 bytes it gives us 32/50 ms ~= 0.64 ms to complete ISR.

How do I confirm the point 1 and point 2 I mentioned above? Any pointers will be appreciated.

We also assume that the 8250.c (serial driver) is fairly old and robust and it shouldn't behave the way it is for us.

Let me know if you need more information.

The 8250.c driver can be found at this weblink.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/serial/8250.c?v=2.6.32;a=arm

One more question I have is that the serial port used on our target board is ST16654 based which has following configuration.

```
[PORT_16654] = {
          .name           = "ST16654",
          .fifo_size      = 64,
          .tx_loadsz      = 32,
          .fcr            = UART_FCR_ENABLE_FIFO | UART_FCR_R_TRIG_01 |
                            UART_FCR_T_TRIG_10,
          .flags          = UART_CAP_FIFO | UART_CAP_EFR | UART_CAP_SLEEP
          }
```

I checked the code and to me it looks rx trigger is set for 16 bytes wheres as tx trigger is set to 32 bytes (defined at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/serial_reg.h?v=2.6.32;a=arm#L62).

Does any one has any clue why is it so?

Comment: This is caused by *other* device drivers.  They either disable interrupts for too long or there's a higher priority ISR that takes too long.

Comment: Your math is slightly off - sending a byte requires at least 10 bit times: 1 start bit, 8 data bits, and the stop bit (this assumes you're using 8N1: 8 bit data, no parity 1 stop bit). If you enable parity, then sending a byte takes 11 bit times).

Comment: Hi Hans, How do I confirm that it is caused by other device driver? Is there any kernel tool that can provide insight to this?